# Login with $cordovaOauth in Facebook returns null data

Tags: angularjs, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api

I am using $cordovaOauth to authenticate on an Ionic app (angular/cordova) but after settings everything on developers.facebook.com and getting the access_token I call again to get user data, but it returns an error with data=null.

Code:

```
  $scope.facebookLogin = function() {
    $cordovaOauth.facebook(FACEBOOK_ID, ["email", "public_profile"], {
      redirect_uri: "http://localhost/callback"
    }).then(function(result) {
      var access_token = result.access_token;
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

      $http.get("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me", {
        params: {
          access_token: access_token,
          fields: "first_name,last_name,gender,picture,locale",
          format: "json"
        }
      }).then(function(result) {
        console.log("RETURN: " + JSON.stringify(result)); // Here is where I see that JSON data
      }, function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error);
      });

    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

And here is the returned JSON:

```
{
  "data": null,
  "status": -1,
  "config": {
    "method": "GET",
    "transformRequest": [null],
    "transformResponse": [null],
    "params": {
      "access_token": "EAAS8ChUdfHEBALdJimUl5TA1sfWGZAZBv8lxlRlpcSaMhKo1NQX5JEgVuTjjpYP4agdZBZCXO0vwFJs0kLXr5CEz2h35JPZAhls9ZBVyyuwfQFlfWQkFDyGMVxsZBmGZA0s6F6XO97HpJRd7c7iZCuwEHhZAKfnMdoKerT0s5HHPW3xAZDZD",
      "fields": "first_name,last_name,gender,picture,locale",
      "format": "json"
    },
    "url": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    "withCredentials": true
  },
  "statusText": ""
}
```

Anybody has an idea of what's wrong?

Comment: Status of -1 often is a CORS problem, a violation of the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: I imagined that, so I added that Facebook URL in my whitelist: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src 'self' *.facebook.com data: *.ngrok.io;  default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' *.facebook.net 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://localhost:35729"> - Still same problem. BTW thanks for answering.

Comment: Look at [MDN Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) and [pre-flight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS#Preflighted_requests_in_CORS).